# how to convert model checking logic query to SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, semantic-web, ontology

Suppose I have the following RDF data:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:m  :A  "a"
:m  :A  "b"
:m  :A  "c"
:m  :B  "a"
:m  :B  "b"
```

What SPARQL query could I use to check whether the RDF model satisfies the following logical formula?

```
∀x A(X) → B(x)
```

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256452/is-it-possible-to-express-a-recursive-definition-in-sparql .

Comment: There's a specification that describes exactly how to do this http://docs.stardog.com/icv/icv-specification.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SPARQL doesn't have conditionals or universal quantification, but does have existentials (does anything match this?), (implicit) conjunction and negation (in the 'absence' sense).

So rewrite the question:

```
∀x A(x) → B(x) ⇒
∀x ¬ ( A(x) ∧ ¬ B(x) ) ⇒
¬ ∃x A(x) ∧ ¬ B(x)
```

and that's something SPARQL can do, pretty much:

```
# Is there anything of type A but not B?
ASK {
  { ?x a :A } MINUS { ?x a :B }
}
```

This query returns *true* if there are any violations of the constraint.

Comment: This is a very nice use of [**minus**](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#neg-minus).  I tend to use **not exists** by default (e.g., `?x a :A . filter not exists { ?x a :B }`, because **minus** can be a bit surprising at times (they don't always produce the same results), but this is a good example of correct use of **minus**.

Comment: One more note on  "If that returns false the test has passed." That's absolutely correct, but it might be easier to think of in terms of the *positive* form of the statement: "The query returns *true* if there are any violations of the constraint."

Comment: Text stolen :-) Yes, minus feels better here, but like you I incline to filter not exists.